# how to express `int.class` in c#(xamarin)?

Tags: c#, types, xamarin.android

we can write below in java:

```
Method method = extraNotification.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(“setMessageCount”, int.class);
```

but when write in c#(xamarin):

```
var method = extraNotification.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("setMessageCount", Class.ForName("java.lang.Integer"));
```

it will throw `{Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException}`

seems that `Class.ForName("java.lang.Integer")` is not equal `int.class`, so how to express the later?

Comment: something like `Class.ForName("java.lang.Integer").getField("TYPE").get(null)`

Comment: Are you trying to get a specific method out of the class that `extraNotification` is a type of? You can use reflection, ie: `extraNotification.GetType().GetMethod("setMessageCount", BindingFlags.Public)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @Selvin,

the java `int.class` can be retrieved as below:

```
var ic = Class.ForName("java.lang.Integer").GetField("TYPE").Get(null) as Class;
var method = extraNotification.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("setMessageCount", ic );
```